# Using fopen() and fread() for a search feature for website

Tags: php, fopen, fread, filesize, strip-tags

**So I been at this for hours and maybe someone can shed some light on me.**

I have this array of files to be searched in.

```
$searchfiles = array(
"index"=>"Home"

);
```

Next I have a loop which goes through the array to search for the keyword I typed in a search form so it would be like ...

```
    $xsearch = $_POST['xsearch'];
```

Following  would be the loop with comments next to the echo statements

```
    $snippetlength=400;

    $resultcount = 1;

    foreach ($searchfiles as $searchpage=>$resulttitle) {

        $searchpagephp = $searchpage . ".php";
        $handle = fopen($searchpagephp, 'r');
        $readpage = fread($handle,filesize($searchpagephp));
        echo $readpage; **//OVER HERE I GET THE ENTRIE PAGE AND SEE THE KEYWORD IM LOOKING FOR**
        $strippedpage = strip_tags($readpage);
        echo $strippedpage; **// OVER HERE I ONLY GET CSS STYLES** 
            if (stripos($strippedpage,$xsearch)) {

            $howmanyoccur = substr_count(strtolower($strippedpage),strtolower($xsearch));
            $searchtermlocation = stripos($strippedpage,$xsearch);
            if ($searchtermlocation-($snippetlength/2)<0) { $resultstart=0; } else { $resultstart=($searchtermlocation-($snippetlength/2)); }
            $displayresult = substr($strippedpage,$resultstart,$snippetlength);

            echo "<li><h2>$resulttitle Page <i>(Hits: $howmanyoccur)</i><br></h2>... " . str_ireplace($xsearch, ("<span style='background-color:#ffff00; font-weight:bold;'>" . strtoupper($xsearch) . "</span>"), $displayresult) . " ...<br><a href=\"$searchpage.php\">Jump to $resulttitle Page</a><br></li><br>";

            $resultcount = $resultcount+1;

            }

        fclose($handle);

    }

    if ($resultcount==1) { echo "<li><i>We're sorry, but no results were found matching your search term.</i><br></li>"; }
```

**So what Im trying to ask is why am I only getting CSS from the index file on Strip tags function?**

Shouldnt I get just plain text entirely?

INDEX FILE provided
[Index file as html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1usFwoKY0EVqujIbw-wzWTanqtbfUtmcP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried `file_get_contents` as an alternative? how dynamic is the page you're trying to search though? you won't get the string you're trying to search if they're rendered using ajax of sorts. and finally, since you're just after part of the string maybe you can just remove that `strip_tags`

Comment: @Kevin it's pretty heavy on the coding part. Has 4 includes and quite a few of jQuery scripts. See edits above. Does file get contents operate differently than fread()?

Comment: it should have no difference actually. take out the `strip_tags` as it strips off some important strings inadvertently. your code works without it. it's hard to play with DOM if you aren't using like `DOMDocument`. if you want to get the needle and the whole excerpt with it, might be better to consider that route too, but that's a whole another topic

Comment: @Kevin but now Im getting html tags next to the keyword if there are html tags near it.